# Preserve indentation in C++ comments in vim

Tags: c++, vim, indentation

Is it possible to configure vim and cindent to not alter indentation in c++ comments when reindenting the file (gg=G) ?

I have some formated lists in comments aligned with 4 spaces but vim interpret this as bad indent and realign everything.

For example:

```
/**
    my list:
         * item 1
         * item 2
 */
```

becomes:

```
/**
    my list:
    * item 1
    * item 2
*/
```

I want a way to tell vim: "Don't touch to comments content but indent everything else."

It is important because our project use doxygen with a markdown like parser to generate documentation and indentation is used by list levels.

Comment: You may want to look at `:help C-indenting` and `:help C-indenting` and finally `:help indentexpr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by review, I repost an answer with answer from [vi stackexchange community](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13962/13084) here:

> I don't believe it's possible to achieve this with `'cinoptions'`.
>
> The correct solution is probably to write a new `indentexpr` that applies C-indenting (accessible via the `cindent()` function) only to lines that aren't within comments.
>
> However, here's a couple of quick and dirty solutions:

I skipped first solution which I don't use and is therefore not the answer. You can still see it on the original post.

> ### Using a Function
>
> ```
> function! IndentIgnoringComments()
>  let in_comment = 0
>   for i in range(1, line('$'))
>     if !in_comment
>       " Check if this line starts a comment
>       if getline(i) =~# '^\s*/\*\*'
>         let in_comment = 1
>       else
>         " Indent line 'i'
>         execute i . "normal =="
>       endif
>     else
>       " Check if this line ends the comment
>       if getline(i) =~# '\*\/\s*$'
>         let in_comment = 0
>       endif
>     endif
>   endfor
> endfunction
> ```
>
> You can run this with `:call IndentIgnoringComments()` or you could set up a command or a mapping. e.g.:
>
> ```
> nnoremap <leader>= :call IndentIgnoringComments()<CR>
> ```

I personaly defined a `command` which call this function and combine it with another reformating I apply often on files in this project (`:%s/\s*$//g`).

Thank to [Rich](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/343/rich) on https://vi.stackexchange.com

Original post: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13962/13084

Answer (score 3):

How about writing like this so in-comment indentation is independent of comment indentation:

```
/**
*    my list:
*        * item 1
*        * item 2
*/
```

Comment: The problem with that syntax is that it's against our project coding conventions. Additionally, how to make it work with existing code which does not use such syntax ?

Comment: @fievel Those "walls" on the left side are used in most of doc comment styles specifically to separate in-comment indentation. It is strange that your project coding conventions gave up such a common good practice. 1) update project coding conventions 2) update existing code to follow updated project coding conventions

Comment: I definitively agree but I cannot, it's a big project and I'm a simple developer.

Comment: In fact I verified, it can be used but we cannot change existing comments by adding such "wall". So I will do it for new files and be careful with indentation of existing ones (or find a way to exclude it, so I don't mark this answer accepter).